# LINQ Orderby Max Distance between keys

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a system that is inserting data from a large unsorted list of objects into a storage system. The storage system assigns processing for the inserts based on the TypeKey for the object(note - there are secondary keys that provide uniqueness). There are multiple objects with the same TypeKey, but this is not distributed equally in the list of objects. If I insert too many of the same key sequentially the process can become throttled, so there is a strong advantage to not do this.

My goal is to take the unsorted list of objects and add them to a thread safe queue in an order that maximizes (or best try), the distance between objects with the same TypeKey.

Note - I am doing this in C# on .NET framework 4.6. I would like to avoid to many outside dependencies if I can avoid it.

Example:

```
    class DataPack
    {
        public string TypeKey {get; set;} 
        public string UniqueKey {get; set;}
        public object DataPackage {get; set;}
    }
```

Pseudo code

```
List<DataPack> rawList = {lotsa data, ~80k datapacks spread across 3000+ keys}
List<DataPack> maxDistSortedList = rawList.OrderByMaxDist();  //Not real function
ConcurrentQueue<DataPack> cq = new ConcurrentQueue<DataPack>();

ForEach (DataPack item in maxDistSortedList)
   {
      cq.Enqueue(item);
   }
```

I would then be drawing from the ConcurrentQueue inside a parallel process to send the data to the storage system.

At this point I am brainstorming ideas for creating the sorting algo, but I seem to be hitting a wall for an efficient process that doesn't involve a large number of iterations through multiple loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've probably missed something, but the idea is to group them first by Typekey, then use the select method that takes two parameters to assign each entry within a typekey group an index, then order by that index.  Then it will take the first entry of TypeKey-1, the first of TypeKey-2, the first of TyperKey-n, then start over taking the second of TypeKey-1, etc.

```
var newList=rawList
    .GroupBy(x=>x.TypeKey)
    .Select(x=>x.Select((y,i)=>new {y=y,i=i}))
    .SelectMany(x=>x)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.i)
    .Select(x=>x.y);
```

Test code:

```
void Main()
{
    var massdata=new List<DataPack>(){
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0000",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0001",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0002",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0003",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0004",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0005",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0006",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0007",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0008",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0001",UniqueKey="0009",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0010",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0011",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0012",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0013",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0014",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0015",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0016",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0017",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0018",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0002",UniqueKey="0019",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0020",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0021",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0022",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0023",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0024",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0025",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0026",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0027",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0028",DataPackage="yes"},
        new DataPack {TypeKey="0003",UniqueKey="0029",DataPackage="yes"},
    };
    var result=massdata
    .GroupBy(x=>x.TypeKey)
    .Select(x=>x.Select((y,i)=>new {y=y,i=i}))
    .SelectMany(x=>x)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.i)
    .Select(x=>x.y);
    result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class DataPack
{
   public string TypeKey {get; set;} 
   public string UniqueKey {get; set;}
   public object DataPackage {get; set;}
}
```

Result:

[image]

Now you will have issues at the very end if there is one type key that has more entries than the others because they will all be that type key, but this was a quick solution, not necessarily the best one.

Comment: Effectively you have the idea. The only thing I would point out as different than your example is that the number of any one TypeKey is very random. There could be 50 of typekey 0001, 6000 of TypeKey 0002, 2154 of TypeKey 0003, etc. Thanks for the ideas. Now I need to work through your code and test it out.

Comment: The process will still work, but it will get less and less efficient as it get towards the end as more and more typekeys run out of entries.  It isn't THE best optimization, just a very easy one.  Optimally ordering them would require a deeper look into the distribution of each typekey.

Comment: You can do this by getting a count of each typekey into a group, and total records.  So for example, if you have 5 if typekey 0001, then optimally, you want 1 record at the beginning and after each 1/4th (1/(5-1)) of the way through the total records.  Loop from 1 to total_records and find the group that has deviated furthest from it's most optimal position, and pull that one.

Comment: Robert, Thank you for the extensive example and follow up comments. I followed your pattern and the result seems to be doing a good job for me. Its primary use was distributing the inserts of BatchTableElements in an Azure Table insert. I am marking your suggestion as the answer.